# How to use an eclipse variable for include path

Tags: eclipse-cdt

Using eclipse luna sr2 on 32 bit linux host.
For my cdt (managed make) project, I' defined some variables, so that in my `.project` were something like this:

```
<variableList>
    <variable>
        <name>Foundation</name>
        <value>$%7BPARENT-3-PROJECT_LOC%7D/Framework</value>
    </variable>
    <variable>
        <name>Cubehal</name>
        <value>$%7BPARENT-3-PROJECT_LOC%7D/Framework/lib/Stm/STM32Cube_FW_F4_V1.9.0</value>
    </variable>
    <variable>
        <name>Freertos</name>
        <value>$%7BPARENT-3-PROJECT_LOC%7D/Framework/lib/FreeRtos/FreeRtos_8.2.2</value>
    </variable>
</variableList>
```

(I e.g. use that for `<linkedResources>` …)

Now I also want to reuse this variables for the include paths (in `.cproject`) but fail when try to expand them. I tried to use `${env_var:…}` like `${env_var:Foundation}/include` but the `${env_var:Foundation}` part always expands to an empty string (it works when using with an OS environment variable, but not with a variable defined in `.project`).

Any suggestion how to solve this?